# What does the operator // do in perl?

Tags: perl

I have come up with a code of below kind :
$avr =  ($values[0] // $values[1]) eq '-' ? 0 : ($values[0] // $values[1]);

Does '//' mean something here?

Comment: https://perldoc.perl.org/perlop.html#Logical-Defined-Or

Comment: Got perfect answer. Thanks @ysth

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
EXPR1 // EXPR2
```

is equivalent to

```
defined(EXPR1) ? EXPR1 : EXPR2
```

except `EXPR1` is only evaluated once.

---

```
my $var = $values[1] // $values[2];
$var = 0 if $var eq '-';
```

is probably clearer than

```
my $var = ($values[0] // $values[1]) eq '-' ? 0 : ($values[0] // $values[1]);
```